# Cant stick a div to the bottom of his parent div

Tags: html, css

hello everyone i am trying to create

a div that will Functioned as the bottom border of

this form, like this:

[image]

The problem is that it only works if I use

margin-top and i dont want to use that.

this is what i am getting now:

[image]

my css:

```
#form_div
{
position: absolute;
top:67px;
left:450px;
height:550px;
-moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 45px #000000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 45px #000000;
box-shadow: 2px 3px 45px #000000;
border-radius: 15px; 
-moz-border-radius: 15px; 
-webkit-border-radius: 15px; 

}
#bottum_border
{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    cursor: e-resize;
    margin-top: 43px;
}
```

my html:

```
  <div id="form_div" class="black_background_solid" >
            <div id="form_headline" class="light_black">Contact Us</div>

                      <div id='n_1_conteiner'  class='field_conteiner'>
                          <div id='n_1_lbl' class="field_name">Name:</div>     
                          <input id='n_1_textbox'  class='textbox gray white_text'  type='text'/>
                           <a id='n_1_edit_btn' class='edit_button'>Edit</a> 
                           <a id='n_1_drop_btn' class='drop_button'>Drop</a> 
                           <div id='n_1_border' class='fakeHr line_border_color_black'></div>
                     </div>

                 <div id='n_5_conteiner'  class='field_conteiner'>
               <div id='n_5_lbl' class='field_name'>Message:</div>
                    <textarea id='n_5_tbx'  class='text_area gray white_text' rows="2" cols="30">
                    </textarea>     
                    <a id='n_5_edit_btn' class='edit_button'>Edit</a>
                    <a id='n_5_drop_btn' class='drop_button'>Drop</a> 
                 </div>

        <div id='results_div'>
            <div id='submit_btn' class="button red_gradient" onclick="Validate()">
                    Submit</div>
        </div>
                      <div id='bottum_border'></div> 
 </div>
```

exact codes pasted in fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z982S/

Comment: what you want the first image?

Comment: Can you give us a jsfiddle or at least include all of the css so someone else can do it...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing height (Use padding/margin instead) from: `#form_div` & add following to `#bottum_border`

```
#bottum_border
{
    position:relative;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something like this:

```
#form_div
{
  position: relative;
}

#submit_btn
{
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

This positions the button to the bottom of the form.

Comment: I'm guessing the form itself must be absolute positioned on top of other things...

Comment: @Baszz - why I don't think so.

Comment: @Baszz - No, the form would have position:relative.

Answer (score 0):

```
#bottum_border
{
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
    cursor: e-resize;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Check fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Zd4fr/

Answer (score 0):

If you want something like 1st image then Why don't you use `border-bottom` directly to the `form_div`?

```
#form_div
{
 border-bottom:1px solid red;

}
```